# Winsock code crashing in freeaddrinfo

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm having trouble with some networking code that use freeaddrinfo(...) with Visual Studio 2012 x64. The code looks something like this:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // only use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags =  AI_ADDRCONFIG;

struct addrinfo *res = nullptr;
int status = getaddrinfo(_rIP.c_str(), std::to_string(_port).c_str(), &hints, &res);
if (status == 0)
{
    addDestAddress(res->ai_addr);
}

freeaddrinfo(res);
```

getaddrinfo/freeaddrinfo is used in a few places throughout the code and I get consistent
crashes in release mode. The code for addDestAddress is as follows:

```
void addDestAddress(const sockaddr *_pAddr)
{
    m_vecDestAddrs.push_back(*(sockaddr_storage*)_pAddr);
}
```

Is this the correct usage of freeaddrinfo? If I remove the freeaddrinfo calls everything works perfectly, except for the possible memory leaks.

**EDIT**
This code now works perfectly. Edited according to Remy Lebeau's answer.

```
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;  // only use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags =  AI_ADDRCONFIG;

struct addrinfo *res = nullptr;
int status = getaddrinfo(_rIP.c_str(), std::to_string(_port).c_str(), &hints, &res);
if (status == 0)
{
    if (res->ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
        addDestAddress((sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

The code for addDestAddress is then as follows:

```
void addDestAddress(const sockaddr_in *_pAddr)
{
    sockaddr_storage ssaddr = {0};
    memcpy(&ssaddr, _pAddr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    m_vecDestAddrs.push_back(ssaddr);
}
```

This is only used for IPv4 UDP work and no IPv6 support is required.

Comment: Your code is very vague, maybe you should try to condense your *real* code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Probably you didn't match the `getaddrinfo` and `freeaddrinfo` calls correctly or ignored the status code. The real issue is not apparent from your code snippet but will emerge when you try to boil your actual code down to a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

1. you are calling `freeaddrinfo()` even if `getaddrinfo()` fails.  Don't do that.
2. you are assuming that `res->ai_addr` is a `sockaddr_storage*`, but it is not.  It is a `sockaddr_in*` instead, because `hints.ai_family` is `AF_INET` (had you used `AF_INET6`, it would be `sockaddr_in6` instead, and `AF_UNSPEC` could be either one). `sockaddr_in` is smaller than `sockaddr_storage` so you are accessing memory incorrectly when copying the `ai_addr` data into your vector.

Try this instead:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // only use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags =  AI_ADDRCONFIG;

struct addrinfo *res = nullptr;
int status = getaddrinfo(_rIP.c_str(), std::to_string(_port).c_str(), &hints, &res);
if (status == 0)
{
    addDestAddress((sockaddr_in*) res->ai_addr);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}

void addDestAddress(const sockaddr_in *_pAddr)
{
    sockaddr_storage ssaddr = {0};
    memcpy(&ssaddr, _pAddr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    m_vecDestAddrs.push_back(ssaddr);
}
```

Or this:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // only use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags =  AI_ADDRCONFIG;

struct addrinfo *res = nullptr;
int status = getaddrinfo(_rIP.c_str(), std::to_string(_port).c_str(), &hints, &res);
if (status == 0)
{
    addDestAddress(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}

void addDestAddress(const sockaddr *_pAddr, int addrlen)
{
    switch (addrlen)
    {
        case sizeof(sockaddr_in):
        case sizeof(sockaddr_in6):
        {
            sockaddr_storage ssaddr = {0};
            memcpy(&ssaddr, _pAddr, addrlen);
            m_vecDestAddrs.push_back(ssaddr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code to use the correct address structure sizes and now everything works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx), with my emphasis:

> Memory allocated by a **successful** call to this function must be released with a subsequent call to freeaddrinfo.

You are not heeding this instruction. You call `freeaddrinfo` unconditionally. You must only call `freeaddrinfo` when the call to `getaddrinfo` is successful.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but unfortunately in my case it did not help.

Comment: That's all that is obvious from the code you provided. Until you provide an SSCCE, don't expect much more than what I wrote.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the crash outside of the application. When I break into the code after a crash it always ends up around the freeaddrinfo calls and the application runs fine without the calls. I will keep on testing and post an SSCCE as soon as I have one.

Comment: Which `getaddrinfo()` implementations actually do the dirty deed of writing garbage into the output pointer when not returning success? glibc does not: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.34/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c#L2470